# Spring MVC Controller : private shared methods. Pass by value and thread safety

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-mvc, parameter-passing

I know that all request are handled by one instance of a controller (singleton because it's a spring managed bean).

I also know that you should not store any state in an instance variable as it's not thread safe.

However looking at this

http://www.programcreek.com/2011/08/so-java-passes-object-by-reference-or-by-value/

Is the below (pseudo) code okay in terms of thread safety?

Can I call changeApple in this way? Pass by value can be confusing and adding thread safety in amongst Spring Magic sometimes get me worried.... :)

```
@Controller
@SessionAtrribute("apple")
@RequestMapping("/foo")
public class FooController {

    @Autowired
    AppleRepository repository;

   @RequestMapping("/method1")
   public String method1(@ModelAttribute("apple") Apple apple) {
       //do some method1 stuff
       changeApple(apple);
       repository.save(apple);
       return "view1";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/method2")
    public String method2(@ModelAttribute("apple") Apple apple) {
       //do some method2 stuff
       changeApple(apple);
       repository.save(apple);
       return "view2"
    }

    private void changeApple(Apple apple) {
        //apple changing stuff
    }
}
```

Will the repository get the right apple and will the right apple be returned to the views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is ok, as apple is always on the stack and is not shared - that is if apple was a request parameter. Since it's a SessionAttribute there is a slight chance that two requests of the same session will be called concurrently and then you will have a undesired race condition.

Comment: Thanks for that.  if I add a return type of Apple to the changeApple method and do the following `apple = changeApple(apple);
       apple = repository.save(apple); model.addAttribute("apple",apple); return "view2";` will that be better?

Comment: It will be better if the method will create a new Apple instance if you  afraid of race condition on session/context variable

Comment: thanks for that - just one last question. How would we get "two requests of the same session will be called concurrently " ?. Would this be if you have multiple tabs with the same user? Even then I would imagine this would be hard to pull off?